# Extract a key/value object type from the properties of an array of objects in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I have a constant array of objects that use the same properties. Something like this:

```
const allData = [{
  name: 'info', content: Info
},{
  name: 'other', content: Other
},{
  ...
}];
```

Now I want to create a variable that after some other code is run, will map these into an object where the keys are the strings of the **name** property and the values are instances of the **content** property. Given that, I want to know how I can define such a type in Typescript that would basically extract those properties from my constant so that it becomes like this in the end:

```
Type ContentInstances = {
  info: Info,
  other: Other 
  ...
}
```

Is there such a way using typeof and other things on Typescript to achieve this dynamically based on **allData** constant?

**EDIT**
Basically at a later stage, I will have something like this:

```
let myVar: ContentInstances;
...
myVar = allData.reduce((obj, value) => {
  obj[value.name] = new value.content(customParam);
  return obj;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
const allData = [
  {
    name: "info",
    content: { hey: "you" },
  },
  {
    name: "other",
    content: { bro: "chill" },
  },
] as const;

type ContentInstances = {
  [K in typeof allData[number]["name"]]: Extract<
    typeof allData[number],
    { name: K }
  >["content"];
};

declare const foo: ContentInstances;

foo.info.hey;
foo.other.bro;
```

The type `ContentInstances` iterates through all the `"name"` keys of the objects contained into `allData`. It maps each key into the union of the objects having that key, to then indexing the union with the `"content"` key.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work but could you explain it a bit, so I can understand what each part does?

Comment: @CristianoSantos I've added an explaination

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to first type your constant variable with `as const` to allow for TypeScript to have smart inference on the types of literals.  After  that, you can combine this with mapped types to create a new type.

```
const allData = [{
  name: 'info', content: { hey: "you" }
}, {
  name: 'other', content: { bro: "chill" }
}] as const;

// the intersection lets us pick out the types in the array that match
// the given `name` property type
type ContentInstances =
  { [K in typeof allData[number]["name"]]: typeof allData[number] & { readonly name: K } }

const foo: ContentInstances["info"] = {
  name: "info",
  content: {
    hey: "you",
    // @ts-expect-error this correctly fails
    asdf: 2,
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQETlOMC8MDaBvAKBhjDgFsBTALhgHIBLMAMxFoBoZQwoLua8YACwoBPGgCIRIAK7iYAXwLyOhYqUo1aIKMIBO7TuB58YAgEa6QE4IPpI5i+QF14EQ5CgBuAgSgiADhQwAMJGvFAAkh5wYMAUbphEprgA0jCMMH6BIEzwSKjoOGDSZGYUuk444uoU4k5ONFkUOXkoaHBFJWUVMABkyboUcAAm4AgiJOTUMGnyCj5c0DAsViFh3FHQMXEQVYwsdVimSTUS+yDibElcxlD8ScTCYjCSMpcPMAD0nzAAAlAQAC0FAAHoFgFBgbpLLpMrY3KBoRQIeNlnA7BAPnAIMMmDQAExXYiObxAA)

Comment: Hmm, but isn't there a way where I could just say **foo: ContentInstances** and then be able to access "you" like this: `foo.info.hey`? Because I want the keys to be the strings of "name" and the values to be the actual values of "content"

Comment: I edited the question with the reason why I need it like what I said on the comment above